# can I change the default view of tab order in win forms

Tags: .net, winforms

Could we changed the default view of tab order.

Like those control whose tab order shown 1.3,1.1,etc can we change it into single digit itself like 3,1 only.

[image]

Comment: What did I just read?

Comment: Send a feature request to the Microsoft Visual Studio development team.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply assign tab order number in property window of controls.
And on page load do the code for control you want to highlight first -

```
controlObj.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use EDIT - VIEW TAB and click the controls in order you want. But I believe groupboxes are a little bit weird, since the TAB will first jump over controls (the groupboxes) and after, within their controls.